# executing diiferent code for different clients in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect multiple client to server and incrementing value for each connected client but if one client connected number is increment sequentially like 1,2,3 but when 2 nd client connects the number starts from 4,5,1..its fluctuate numbers in two terminal.How to execute different code for different client?

Comment: Hi @Krutika can you provide sample code.

Comment: sequence = 1;ioServer.on('connection', function(socket) {
 
    console.info('New client connected (id=' + socket.id + ').');
    clients.push(socket);
    if(socket.id){
     callclients(sequence);
    }function callclients(sequence){
 setInterval(function() {
 var randomClient;
    if (clients.length > 0) {
     randomClient= Math.floor(Math.random() * clients.length);
        clients[randomClient].emit('foo', sequence++);
    }
}, 1000);
}

Comment: @KrutikaPatil - Multi-line code is completely unreadable in comments.  Use the "edit" link in your question to add the code to your question and then format it properly to make it readable.  It looks like you may be new to stack overflow, but you need to learn the proper way to write clear questions.

Comment: Are you trying to make sequence numbers that are uniquely incrementing for each client?  So, the first client would see `1,2,3` and then the second client would see `1,2,3`?  Or do you just want a monotonically increasing number as long as it's always a uniquely increasing number for every client?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the statefulness nature of NodeJS. Create an object with the following structure:

```
'use strict';

let obj = {
    UNIQUE_ID: Integer
}
```

Where the UNIQUE_ID is an ID that the client will be identified with. You can randomly create a number and store it in the user cookie for example.

Then when the client connects to the server, you increment that specific UNIQUE_ID. For example:

```
'use strict';

let obj = {
    "5": 0
};

obj["5"]++;

console.log(obj);
```

You can read more about the statefulness of NodeJS [hear](https://github.com/davidgatti/Statefulness-aspect-of-NodeJS).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want what is commonly called a "session" in node.js.  A session creates an object in node.js that is uniquely associated with each separate client that is connecting to your server and you can accumulate or collect information across different requests from the same server.

A session works by doing the following:

1. The first time a client connects to a server, the server coins a unique identifier for that client and sets it into a cookie.
2. The server then creates a session object using the unique client id as a key into some server-side data structure.
3. The server code handling requests can then read or write any values it wants to that session.
4. Upon subsequent requests by the same client, the server can fetch the client identifier from the cookie and can then lookup the corresponding session object on the server and can get access to the "session data" for that client.
5. To keep session objects from accumulating forever, there is usually some sort of timeout or cleanup mechanism to remove old sessions.

For all common http server frameworks in the node.js world, there will already be modules that implement this session concept.  For example, the Express framework has multiple NPM modules that implement sessions, the most common is probably [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

Using a session structure like this then allows you to keep track of some state separately for each connecting client and to maintain that state from one request from that client to the next.  You can then implement your own logic based on the status of that client state to execute different code for one request vs. another.